# unable to get property of 'sku' undefined or null reference

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have the following jquery code in Google Tag Manager

```
for(item in cartObject){
        ga(ec:addProduct,{"id":cartObject[item][sku],"name":cartObject[item][Name],"category":cartObject[item][categories],"brand":cartObject[item][_0xad1e[5]],"price":cartObject[item][_0xad1e[16]],"quantity":cartObject[item][_0xad1e[30]]})};
        ga(_0xad1e[6],_0xad1e[38],{"step":_0xc357x7});
        ga(_0xad1e[8],_0xad1e[9],_0xad1e[10],_0xad1e[11],_0xad1e[39]+_0xc357x7,{"nonInteraction":1});
        }
```

That is suppose to get the variables from the success.html page of my website

```
           orderObject['0'] = {
                'sku': '161',
                'Name': 'Trappist Ale Discovery (12 bottles) plus free Chalice Glass',
                'Price': '38.5',
                'qty': '1.0000',
                'categories':'Discovery Cases,Belgian Beers,Browse All Our Beers,Browse by Style,Browse Mixed Cases,Abbey and Trappist',
                'brand':''
            }
            var transactionObject = {};
                transactionObject = {
                    'tid': '100029250',
                    'aid': 'Beer Hawk',
                    'revenue': '6.9900',
                    'tax': '7.5800',
                    'shipping': '6.9900',
                    'ccode': ''
             }
```

It works in all browsers apart from Internet Explorer which gives the following message in the console

```
unable to get property of 'sku' undefined or null reference
```

My code start with the following

```
<script>
jQuery(document)[ready]

(function()

{
```

I have looked at changing bits of my code but nothing seems to work in Internet Explorer, I need to get the variables to send them to Google Analytics

Comment: There is no variable "cartObject" (requested in your first code snippet) in your second code example, so I don't think this is the complete/correct code.

Answer (score 0):

In this piece (and others)

```
cartObject[item][sku]
```

item is a variable
sku is not - it should be a string

try

```
cartObject[item]["sku"]
```

or

```
cartObject[item].sku
```

etc